# Javascript: Convert GMT Time to PST

Tags: javascript, time

My backend is currently supplying my frontend with the following information:

```
time: {
    stamp: '2013-11-03T18:12:39',
    timezone: 'PST'
}
```

I'm currently using Moment.js to convert the time into a more readable string: `11/03/2013 6:12 PM PST`

However, this is not accurate as the original time is in GMT. How can I apply the timezone conversion using the string 'PST'?

Does anyone know of a library that can assist in doing so or will I be required to code a long switch that would look at the string and offset the time from there for all timezones applicable to the application?

Moment.js has a timezone conversion tool, however it uses location information not timezone short forms.

Comment: [Definitely don't handle the time zones yourself!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Comment: Can't you do the conversion in the backend?

Comment: Leaning towards suggesting it.. I am not the BE programmer. Is it easier done in .NET that way?

Comment: @Neil: I don't know .NET, but it might be.

Comment: If the backend just serialized `DateTime` objects in JSON correctly, everything would just magically work.  The timezone of the server would be taken into account, the time would be serialized across the wire in UTC, and the time would display in JavaScript according to the local timezone.  Ask the backend developer(s) to serialize their `DateTime` objects correctly; this is truly not your problem to deal with.

Comment: [I think this article will answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)